# Android Room Not Recognizing Column Name From Schema (using an alias for column name)

Tags: android, android-room

I am relatively new to Android Development and using its Room persistence library. The problem I am currently facing is the following error:

`error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: s_abb)`

However my table schema (that this column is being referenced by) does contain this column by this name. Here is how I defined my entity in Android

```
@Entity
public class stops {

@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "s_name")
private String s_name;
@Ignore
@ColumnInfo(name = "s_abb")
private String s_abb;
@Ignore
@ColumnInfo(name = "Comments")
private String Comments;

public String getS_abb() {
    return s_abb;
}

public void setS_abb(String s_abb) {
    this.s_abb = s_abb;
}

public String getS_name() {
    return s_name;
}

public void setS_name(String s_name) {
    this.s_name = s_name;
}

public String getComments() {
    return Comments;
}

public void setComments(String comments) {
    Comments = comments;
}


}
```

I have tested the query in SQLite Studio and it does return expected data. Here is a screen shot of query written within DAO Interface: [Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqJC0.png). I personally think the main problem is that Room may not recognize the aliases I am using with my subqueries and the column names. Am I correct in thinking this? I hope my screenshot helps. I did make sure to add proper spacing between SQL statements, as many solutions here have pointed out. If any of you need me to provide more information, I am happy to oblige! Thank you

Comment: Your column is marked with the Ignore annotation and... Ignored by Room! Please see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Ignore

Comment: You should only use @Ignore for the fields you're not going to save in the persistence store. I.e. helper fields like received date and other stuff you might need, while the object is being used in memory.

Comment: Oh wow, that flew right passed me. Thanks! I just read the documentation you sent me (thanks btw). Just to confirm, @Ignore should just be used for columns that will not be used throughout the application? Now I am getting an error that the columns returned by my query does not have fields s_name. But when I run it on SQLite it does return s_name values. Could this be an aliasing issue?

Comment: Remove all your Ignore annotations and try to clean/rebuild (or even invalidate android studio cache, then clean rebuild). Also you'd rather not using underscores in your column name aliases, try to use names like stopName, stopAdd and getters/setters like getStopAdd etc.

Comment: Thank you sir, I took out the ignore statements and I also realized that my query was returning two column values that are strings, however my method was expecting an Entity type. I'll make sure to place both as an answer as soon as I get out of class! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As Vladimir Gladun pointed out, the column `s_abb` that I was querying for was set with an `@Ignore` annotation over it. Which as Android's documentation on `@Ignore` annotations states that "Ignores the marked element from Room's processing logic": 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Ignore.

Which basically means Room disregards it completely.

However this was not the only problem, My method was expecting `Entity` type values 
whereas the `SELECT` statement from my outermost query was returning `String` type values. Fixing those two errors solved my problem.